# Why does $\overline{\langle f, \phi_n\rangle }\langle f, \phi_n\rangle = |\langle f, \phi_n\rangle|^2$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

If $f(x)$, $\phi_n(x) \in \mathbb{C}$,     $\;\;-\infty<a<x<b<\infty$ and

$$\langle f, \phi_n\rangle = \int_a^b f(x)\overline{\phi_n(x)}\;dx,$$

then why does:

$$\overline{\langle f, \phi_n\rangle }\langle f, \phi_n\rangle = |\langle f, \phi_n\rangle|^2,$$

that is:

$$\overline{\langle f, \phi_n\rangle }\langle f, \phi_n\rangle = \int_a^b \overline{f(x)}\phi_n(x)\;dx\int_a^b f(x)\overline{\phi_n(x)}\;dx $$

$$ = \left| \int_a^b f(x)\overline{\phi_n(x)}\;dx \right|^2 = |\langle f, \phi_n\rangle|^2.$$

The function $\phi_n(x)$ belongs to an orthonormal set in $L^2(a,b)$, which is the space of **square-integrable** functions on $[a,b]$.

Thank you for any help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $z\in \mathbb C$, you have that $$z\overline z = |z|^2$$ because $z=a+bi,\overline z = a-bi$ and $$z\overline z = (a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2 - (bi)^2 = a^2 + b^2 = |z|^2.$$