# Proving that $\langle f, g\rangle = \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n \rangle \overline{\langle g, \phi_n \rangle}$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis

I have the following problem to solve:

> If the set of functions $\{\phi_n \}_1^\infty$ is an orthonormal basis in
>   $L^2(a,b)$ and the functions $f, g \in L^2(a,b)$, then show that:
>
> $$\langle f, g\rangle = \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n \rangle
>  \overline{\langle g, \phi_n \rangle}.$$

The dot product $\langle f, g\rangle$ is defined as:

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_a^b f(x)\overline{g(x)}\;dx.$$

Because $f, g \in L^2(a,b)$, we have:

$$f= \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n \;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;g= \sum_n \langle g, \phi_m\rangle \phi_m.$$

Here is my attempt:

$$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_a^bf(x)\overline{g(x)}\;dx = \int_a^b \left( \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n(x)\right)\left( \overline{\sum_m\langle g, \phi_m\rangle \phi_m(x)}\right) \;dx$$

$$= \int_a^b \left( \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n(x)\right)\left( \sum_m \overline{\langle g, \phi_m\rangle \phi_m(x)}\right) \;dx = \int_a^b\left( \sum_n \int_a^b f(y)\overline{\phi_n(y)}\;dy\;\phi_n (x)\right)\left( \sum_m \int_a^b \overline{g(z)}\phi_m(z)\;dz\;\overline{\phi_m(x)} \right)\;dx$$

$$?=\sum_n \langle f, \phi_n\rangle\overline{\langle g, \phi_n\rangle} = \sum_n\int_a^bf(x)\overline{\phi_n(x)}\;dx\int_a^b\overline{g(y)}\phi_n(y)\;dy$$

So should the last and third line be equal? Thnx for any hints

**UPDATE**:

I think I got it by the hint given to me =) :

$$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_a^bf(x)\overline{g(x)}\;dx = \int_a^b \left( \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n\rangle \phi_n(x)\right)\left( \overline{\sum_m\langle g, \phi_m\rangle \phi_m(x)}\right) \;dx$$

$$=\int_a^b \sum_{n,m}\langle f, \phi_n \rangle\overline{\langle g, \phi_m\rangle}\phi_n(x)\overline{\phi_m(x)} \;dx= \int_a^b \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n \rangle\overline{\langle g, \phi_n\rangle}\phi_n(x)\overline{\phi_n(x)}\;dx$$

$$= \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n \rangle\overline{\langle g, \phi_n\rangle}\int_a^b \phi_n(x)\overline{\phi_n(x)}\;dx = \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n \rangle\overline{\langle g, \phi_n\rangle}\langle \phi_n, \phi_n\rangle = \sum_n \langle f, \phi_n \rangle\overline{\langle g, \phi_n\rangle}\;\;\blacksquare$$

Comment: The answer itself was well answered by Hagen von Eitzen, but I would like to give you a quick advice. Just like another question you asked, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791498/why-does-overline-langle-f-phi-n-rangle-langle-f-phi-n-rangle-langl

it is often easier to answer the questions by using ony the properties of dot products and such. These things are true for all dot products and are easier to prove than by using the integral definition of your particular product.

Comment: See also [Parseval's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem#Statement_of_Parseval.27s_theorem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the properties of $\Phi_n$,
$$f=\sum_n\langle f,\phi_n\rangle \phi_n $$
and $$\langle \phi_n,\phi_m\rangle =\delta_{m,n}.$$